# Save and retrieve login and registration form without database

Tags: javascript, forms, authentication, registration

I have this login and registration form in HTML. Can you suggest what I can use without using mysql or anything server- side database I can only use something like just javascript to fetch the registered account. Tried using localstorage but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to manage a database maybe you can use Firebase as external solution for the authentication.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users?hl=es-419